# HTML5: Get click position from canvas arc

Tags: html, canvas, click, position, geometric-arc

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HETvZ/5/) post for a working arc drawing; thanks to [Simon Sarris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154112/simon-sarris) for the fix in my previous questions.

I'm using the [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com/) plugin to create shapes and make use of event handlers. Assuming you clicked somewhere on the arc and the arc knew where you clicked (`x`, `y`), how could those 2 coordinates be used to determine a percentage?

When you click anywhere, the total percentage is always 100%.

**Addin**

To make this simpler, what could I do to (`x`, `y`) to virtually bend the object so that `x` goes from 0 to maximum `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple trigonometry. `sin(angle) = opposite / adjacent`. `opposite` is the `y` value and `adjacent` is the `x` value. So `Math.asin((xx - x) / (yy - y))` where xx and yy are the coords of the centre of the arc. That gives you the angle, which you can then divide `2 * Math.PI` by.

Off the top of my head I can't remember what happens with negative numbers. You may have to take the `Math.abs` value of the arguments, then work out which quadrant the click is in (easy to do by using `<` and `>`) and add `Math.PI / 2` for each one.

Answer (score 1):

This includes a check if the mouse is inside the arc:

```
// Return range is 0 to Math.PI * 2
function get_mouse_circle_angle(origin_x, origin_y, mouse_x, mouse_y) {
    var mouse_angle = Math.atan2(mouse_y - origin_y, mouse_x - origin_x);
    if (mouse_angle < 0) {
        mouse_angle = (Math.PI * 2) + mouse_angle;
    }
    return mouse_angle;
}

// Return range is [0, 1)
// 0/1 is 3 oclock
function get_mouse_circle_percent(origin_x, origin_y, mouse_x, mouse_y) {
    var mouse_angle = get_mouse_circle_angle(origin_x, origin_y, mouse_x, mouse_y);
    return mouse_angle / (2 * Math.PI);
}

function get_mouse_arc_pos(origin_x, origin_y, mouse_x, mouse_y, radius, thickness) {
    var mouse_angle = Math.atan2(mouse_y - origin_y, mouse_x - origin_x);
    if (mouse_angle < 0) {
        mouse_angle = (Math.PI * 2) + mouse_angle;
    }
    var mouse_percent = mouse_angle / (2 * Math.PI);

    var circle_edge_x = origin_x + (radius + thickness / 2) * Math.cos(mouse_angle);
    var circle_edge_y = origin_y + (radius + thickness / 2) * Math.sin(mouse_angle);

    var arc_inside_x = origin_x + (radius - thickness / 2) * Math.cos(mouse_angle);
    var arc_inside_y = origin_y + (radius - thickness / 2) * Math.sin(mouse_angle);

    var is_in_circle = true;

    if (mouse_angle <= (2 * Math.PI) * 0.25) {
        if (mouse_x > circle_edge_x || mouse_y > circle_edge_y)
            is_in_circle = false;
    }
    else if (mouse_angle <= (2 * Math.PI) * 0.5) {
        if (mouse_x < circle_edge_x || mouse_y > circle_edge_y)
            is_in_circle = false;
    }
    else if (mouse_angle <= (2 * Math.PI) * 0.75) {
        if (mouse_x < circle_edge_x || mouse_y < circle_edge_y)
            is_in_circle = false;
    }
    else {
        if (mouse_x > circle_edge_x || mouse_y < circle_edge_y)
            is_in_circle = false;
    }

    var is_in_arc = is_in_circle;
    if (is_in_circle) {
        if (mouse_angle <= (2 * Math.PI) * 0.25) {
            if (mouse_x < arc_inside_x || mouse_y < arc_inside_y)
                is_in_arc = false;
        }
        else if (mouse_angle <= (2 * Math.PI) * 0.5) {
            if (mouse_x > arc_inside_x || mouse_y < arc_inside_y)
                is_in_arc = false;
        }
        else if (mouse_angle <= (2 * Math.PI) * 0.75) {
            if (mouse_x > arc_inside_x || mouse_y > arc_inside_y)
                is_in_arc = false;
        }
        else {
            if (mouse_x < arc_inside_x || mouse_y > arc_inside_y)
                is_in_arc = false;
        }
    }

    return {
        angle: mouse_angle,
        percent: mouse_percent,
        is_in_circle: is_in_circle,
        is_in_arc: is_in_arc
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did not really test it, but technically, it should work:

```
// Where x1 and y1 should be the coordinates of the arc's center
function angle(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    // Calculate a · b
    var nominator = x1 * x2 + y1 * y2;

    // Calculate ||a|| ||b||
    var denominator = Math.sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1) * Math.sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
    if (denominator == 0) return 0; // Indifinite angle

    // Return the angle
    return Math.acos(nominator / denominator);
}

// Returns a percent, might be negative
var percent = angle(0, 0, mouseX, mouseY) / (2*Math.PI);
```

### Edit

For negative numbers you can try adding 1 since it's in [-1, 1] range

```
if (percent < 0) percent += 1;
```